# Auto hide "not empty" rows based on a specific cell value using script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I managed to hide the rows if it's not empty when "G1" is "0", however the below script hides the rows starting from row 2. 
i can't figure out how to hide the rows starting from row 3.
Appreciate your Help

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet= ss.getSheetByName("Manadeeb");
  var cellValue= sheet.getRange("G1").getValue()
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  if(cellValue == 0){
    for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
      if(values[i][1] !== "") {
      sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange(i+1,1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it by Trial and Error

```
function onEdit(){

  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet= ss.getSheetByName("Manadeeb");
  var cellValue= sheet.getRange("G1").getValue()
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  if(cellValue == 0){
    for(var i=+2; i<values.length; i++){
      if(values[i][1] !== "") {
      sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange(i+1,1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```